# Using index and match functions with conditional statement to return nonunique values

Tags: excel-formula

I made a power query from the following data:

[image]

The power query returns the CGWS variable max and mins:

[image]

I want to return the corresponding date value that is in the same row as the max or min CGWS. The CGWS max and min values are non-unique (there are multiple occurrences of the same number throughout the column). I've tried to use the index and match function:

```
=INDEX(Table1[[Date]:[CGWS Elev (ft msl)]],MATCH([@[Min CGWS (ft AMSL)]],Well_Gauging_Data!L2:L998,0),1)
```

The above function returns the first occurrence of the match. I need a way to test if the Well ID is correct before returning the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your formula to

```
=INDEX(Well_Gauging_Data!C2:C998,MATCH(1,([@[Min CGWS (ft AMSL)]] = Well_Gauging_Data!L2:L998) * ([@[Well ID]] = Well_Gauging_Data!A2:A998),0),1)
```

And hold Ctl + Shift and press enter. That will create what's called an [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) which, in this case, will test for both a matching "Min CGWS (ft AMSL)" and a matching "Well ID" using a boolean array for each. It then multiplies the two together and retrieves a value from the first non-zero row in the array.